# QT quick2 qml dynamic change GridView columns

Tags: c++, qml, qtquick2

I used a GridView to display a ListModel. Originally I set cellWidth to:

`cellWidth = grid.width/3`

to create a 3 columns grid. then I want to change the column count to 2, so I set cellWidth to:

```
cellWidth = grid.width/2
```

the GridView's display changed. But when I resize the container's desktop window, the cells in the gridview  won't change size anymore.

what should I do to make it correct?

Please have a look at the following code:

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
title: qsTr("Hello World")
width: 640
height: 480

menuBar: MenuBar {
    Menu {
        title: qsTr("File")
        MenuItem {
            text: qsTr("2 columns")
            onTriggered: grid.cellWidth = grid.width/2;
        }
        MenuItem {
            text: qsTr("3 columns")
            onTriggered: grid.cellWidth = grid.width/3;
        }
    }
}

GridView {
    id: grid
    anchors.fill: parent
    cellWidth: width / 3;
    cellHeight: 300;
    model: ListModel {
        ListElement {
            name: "Apple"
            cost: 2.45
        }
        ListElement {
            name: "Orange"
            cost: 3.25
        }
        ListElement {
            name: "Banana"
            cost: 1.95
        }
    }
    delegate : Rectangle {
        //anchors.fill: parent
        width: grid.cellWidth
        height: grid.cellHeight
        border.color: "green"
        border.width: 2
        color: "red"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: i think you need to show some more code so people can try the code and help

Comment: @Kunal tks, I have pasted some code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've solved the problem by defining onWidthChanged of the gridview.

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    width: 640
    height: 480
    id: appwnd
    property int columns : 3;

    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("File")
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("2 columns")
                onTriggered: {
                    columns = 2;
                    grid.cellWidth = grid.width/columns;
                }
            }
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("3 columns")
                onTriggered: {
                    columns = 3;
                    grid.cellWidth = grid.width/columns;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    GridView {
        id: grid
        anchors.fill: parent
        cellWidth: width / 3;
        cellHeight: 300;
        model: ListModel {
            ListElement {
                name: "Apple"
                cost: 2.45
            }
            ListElement {
                name: "Orange"
                cost: 3.25
            }
            ListElement {
                name: "Banana"
                cost: 1.95
            }
        }
        delegate : Rectangle {
            //anchors.fill: parent
            width: grid.cellWidth
            height: grid.cellHeight
            border.color: "green"
            border.width: 2
            color: "red"
        }
        onWidthChanged: {
            grid.cellWidth = grid.width/appwnd.columns;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you were having is that bindings are not automatically set up when you're writing JavaScript (which you're doing in your `onTriggered` signal handlers).

It is possible to do bindings in Javascript (as opposed to pure QML property binding) using `Qt.binding()`:

```
onTriggered: {
    columns = 2;
    grid.cellWidth = Qt.binding(function() { return grid.width/columns; });
}
```

While your `onWidthChanged` handler solution works, this is a cleaner solution.

See: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-propertybinding.html#creating-property-bindings-from-javascript for details on how this works.